# How to open call out MKAnnotationView programmatically? (iPhone, MapKit)

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, mkannotation, callouts

I want to open up the callout for an `MKPinAnnotationView` programmatically. Eg I drop 10 pins on the map, and want to open up the one closest to me. How would I go about doing this?

Apple has specified the 'selected' parameter for `MKAnnotationView's`, but discourages setting it directly (this doesn't work, tried it).

For the rest `MKAnnotationView` only has a setHighlighted (**same story**), and can `ShowCallout` method..

Any hints if this is possible at all?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In your mapViewController create an action method:

```
- (void)openAnnotation:(id)annotation 
{
    //mv is the mapView
    [mv selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];

}
```

You can then determine the closest annotation based on current location and walking the annotations available in the array.

```
[mv annotations];
```

Once the closest annotation is calculated, call:

```
[self openAnnotation:closestAnnotation];
```

The mapView should scroll automatically to place your annotation in the center of the display area.

Comment: Thanks Nate, for fixing the typo.

Comment: If you know the annotation you want to programmatically select will be in the map view's visible area you can use `[mv annotationsInMapRect:mv.visibleMapRect]`. If you're working with large sets of map annotations this will provide a step up in performance.

Comment: True.  The MapKit API has expanded since this answer was originally provided.  The annotationsInMapRect: was added in iOS 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

In swift 3 this is updated to:

```
func openAnnotation(annotation: MkAnnotation) {
_ = [mapView .selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)]
}
```

and can be called using any annotation (this will open the annotation callout view and attempt to center the annotation on the map)

For example using the second annotation in a hypothetical list of annotations.

```
openAnnotation(annotation: mapView.annotations[1])
```

Comment: Your code is a strange mix of ObjC (the square brackets) and Swift. Why create an array then discard it?