# MapView annotation

Tags: iphone, dictionary

I have added an image on annotation view and when i am touching annotation view its image is changeing into red pin can any one tell me what's he reason for it

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
    MKPinAnnotationView* newAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotation1"];

    if (annotation == _mapView.userLocation)
    {
        newAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        return nil;
    }

    //[newAnnotation setSelected:YES];
    newAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
    newAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    newAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
    [newAnnotation retain];

    return newAnnotation;

}
```

Comment: Are you adding the image in MKPinAnnotationView. ?

Comment: If you want some answers I suggest you post some code which will definitely help you better

Comment: you do remove the Annotation when u touching the annotation view

Answer (score 1):

Make the `newAnnotation` a `MKAnnotationView` rather than a `MKPinAnnotationView`.

Comment: i also want to show annotaion selected with call out how can i do it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193843/how-to-open-call-out-mkannotationview-programmatically-iphone-mapkit

Comment: newAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES; will do it.  Or is it something else that you want

Comment: Rog's link will help you if thats what you want

Comment: in which delegate method i should find the closest annotation to current location

Comment: you can make use of [location getDistanceFrom:currentLocation]; to get distance between the coordinates which can help you to find the closest one.