# CLLocationCoordinate2D to MKAnnotation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mapkit, core-location

I have a MapView that I'm trying to add an Annotation at the current Coordinates.

My Code in viewWillAppear:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = [maps.barLat doubleValue];
location.longitude = [maps.barLong doubleValue];
[_mapView addAnnotation:location];
```

I'm getting an error on the `addAnnotation` that says

> Sending CLLocationCoordinate2D to parameter of incompatible type MKAnnotation.

All the other examples I see have no problem with this code, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [Apple's API docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html), the `addAnnotation:` method takes an `id<MKAnnotation>`, not a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.  That's the reason for your error.

If you just want a simple annotation, without any fancy bells or whistles, just do this:

```objc
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = [maps.barLat doubleValue];
location.longitude = [maps.barLong doubleValue];
MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotation.coordinate = location;
[_mapView addAnnotation: annotation];
```

Most people, however, wind up creating their own class that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol, to provide custom annotations.  But, if all you need is a pin, the above will work.

Comment: Thanks for the `MKPointAnnotation` as I only need to create one point and didn't need a separate class.  I've added `annotation.title = maps.barName;` and it works, any idea how to make that appear as soon as the map is shown?

Comment: @user1454340, the annotation isn't appearing as soon as the map is shown? you are using the code above in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`? or are you asking if you can make a callout with the title appear automatically? to do that, [see this stack overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2339556/119114)