# Show annotation while map view opens

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview, ibaction

Is ti possible to show an annotation while a map view is opening? I have looked at other pieces of code, but they all involve objectAtIndex, and I am not using a tableview for this selection.

Here is the code I am using to select the view, which is supposed to open when I click a button:

```
Screen1ViewController

- (IBAction)mapPressed1:(UIButton*)sender
{
mapnew *controller1 = [[[mapnew alloc] initWithNibName:@"mapnew" bundle:nil] autorelease];
controller1.delegate = self;
controller1.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:controller1 animated:YES completion:nil];

// IS IT POSSIBLE TO DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS INTO THE IBACTION FOR IT TO WORK:
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:NameOfAnnotationForSpecificLocationCoordinates animated:YES];
}
```

The map that is supposed to open at the click of a button should be able to recognize where the click came from, and open the right annotation. Each point on the map has a name assigned to it.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean annotation (the pin on the map) or the callout (the popup window that usually shows when someone taps an annotation)?

Comment: I mean annotation as in the callout, but an example with annotation as in the pin will be good too..

Answer (score 0):

Asked and answered here: [How to open call out MKAnnotationView programmatically? (iPhone, MapKit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193843/how-to-open-call-out-mkannotationview-programmatically-iphone-mapkit)

All you need to do is make pass the data to your controller1 so it is ready to show it the moment it appears.