# How to have a MKPinAnnotationView open when pin is dropped

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I currently am dropping a reusable pin using this function:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{

    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { return nil }
    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    }
    pinView?.pinTintColor = UIColor.orange
    pinView?.canShowCallout = true

    let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: smallSquare))
    button.setTitle("Test", for: UIControlState())
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(triggerConfirmedLocation), for: .touchUpInside)

    pinView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
    pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
    return pinView
}
```

Currently the user has to tap on the pin to see the annotation; however, I need the annotation to be open when the pin is dropped.

I have tried these methods:

```
pinView?.isSelected = true
```

and

```
mapView.selectedAnnotations(reuse, animated: true)
```

However the first method does nothing.

The second method has an error of 
"Cannot call value of non-function type '[MKAnnotation]'"

Comment: Point of clarification: It sounds like you want the **callout** view to be opened. The annotation view *is* the pin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193843/how-to-open-call-out-mkannotationview-programmatically-iphone-mapkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this method from `MKMapView` using:

```
func selectAnnotation(_ annotation: MKAnnotation, animated: Bool)
```

You can pass the annotation from the delegate override like so:

```
mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
```

Just call that before returning the `pinView` and you'll be good to go.

Hope that helps.